# Sum of Nested Lists for each key in dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, nested-lists

How do you get the sum of each nested list for each key in the dictionary below?

Let's say the following below is called msgs

[image]

I tried the following code:

[image]

I ended up getting the result:

[image]

It is almost right but for some reason the sum of the first nested list is incorrect, being 0 whereas it should be 19. I have a feeling this has to do with the total = 0 part in the above code I wrote but I am not sure if this is the case and I don't know how to fix the issue.

The way I got the values in the nested list was I summed the number of strings in each index of the nested list. So for instance, this here was for the first key. As you can see, there are 15 entries in the first one and 4 in the second one.

(this dictionary is called 'kakao' in my code)

`{'Saturday, July 28, 2018': [['hey', 'ben', 'u her?', 'here?', 'ok so basically', 'farzam and avash dont wanna go to vegas', 'lol', 'im offering a spontaneous trip me and you to SF', 'lol otherwise ill just go back to LA', 'i mean sf is far but', 'i mean if u really wanna hhah', 'we could go and see chris', 'but otherwise its fine', 'alright send me the code too', 'im on my way right now'], ['Wtf is happening lol', '8 haha', 'Key is #8000', 'Hf']]}`

The code I used to get the sums as a nested list was:

[image]

Comment: Please, paste code snippets instead of pictures of code.

Comment: Is the depth level of each item known beforehand?

Comment: I added some extra information

Comment: nevermind, i got it! I figure it out

Comment: Paste code in code blocks, don't use pictures.

Answer (score 0):

```
kakao = {'Saturday, July 28, 2018': [['hey', 'ben', 'u her?', 'here?', 'ok so basically', \
'farzam and avash dont wanna go to vegas', 'lol', 'im offering a spontaneous trip me and you to SF', \
'lol otherwise ill just go back to LA', 'i mean sf is far but', 'i mean if u really wanna hhah', \
'we could go and see chris', 'but otherwise its fine', 'alright send me the code too', 'im on my way right now'], \
['Wtf is happening lol', '8 haha', 'Key is #8000', 'Hf']],
'Friday, August 3, 2018': [['Someone', 'said', 'something'], ['Just', 'test']],}


print({key: [sum(map(lambda letters: len(letters), val))] for key, val in kakao.items()})


#the result --> {'Saturday, July 28, 2018': [19], 'Friday, August 3, 2018': [5]}
```

I guess you want to count the letters form the sentences at the same day, hope this code can help you.